# Class processing, recurring code

Tags: java, android, realm

I have several classes (for example, realm tables).
I process each in the same way (see code below).

Changing only the name of the class : `Ticket.class`, further it will be `SecondTable.class` and so on.
Class names are known in advance.

**Q1**. How to make one method with an class as argument ?

**Q2**. Or how can I do something like "*for each [classes] do ...*" ?

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<Ticket> tickets = realm.where(Ticket.class).findAll();
realm.beginTransaction();
for (int i = tickets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ... {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)...;
        StartMyAsyncTask().execute(tickets.get(i));
        // etc...

        // delete from DB
        tickets.get(i).removeFromRealm();
    }
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```

And the `Ticket` class looks like:

```
public class Ticket extends RealmObject {... }
```

Comment: open the transaction **before** the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can create an *union* interface:

```
public interface IAction {
    void action(); 
}
```

for `Ticket` and `SecondTable` and implement this:

```
public class Ticket extends RealmObject implements IAction {

    @Override
    public void action(){...}
}
```

The next step is a *template method* (probably, in your `Utils` class):

```
public static <T extends RealmObject & IAction> void yorForEachMethod(Class<T> cls) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults realmObjects = realm.where(cls).findAll();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = realmObjects.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ... {
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)...;
            // you can evaluate implementation of action method from IAction interface
            ((IAction)realmObjects.get(i)).action();
            // or pass to assync task and work with IAction interface
            //StartMyAsyncTask().execute((IAction)realmObjects.get(i));
            // etc...

            // delete from DB
            realmObjects.get(i).removeFromRealm();
        }
    }
    realm.commitTransaction(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can create a method with class as an `Object`:

```
public void yourMethod(Object yourclass) {}
```

2.Since you will be updating object each and every time. Create a new instance and call the above generated method:

```
yourMethodClass.yourMethod(ObjectName);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a sample code that was too simplistic. I made corrections.